# Auto upload remote files into Google cloud storage via FTP?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I download a lot of csv files via ftp from different sources on a daily basis. I then upload these files into Google Cloud Storage.

Are there any programs/api/tools to automate this?

Looking for a best way, if possible, to load these files directly into Google Cloud Storage without having to locally download them. Something that I can deploy on Google Compute, so I don't need to run a local programs like Filezilla/CrossFTP. The program/tool will keep checking the remote location on a regular basis and load new files into Google Cloud Storage; ensuring a checksum match.

I apologize in advance if this is too vague/generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no. Automatically importing objects from a remote FTP server is not currently a feature of GCS.

Comment: Is there any update on this 4.5 years later. Is this still impossible?

Comment: GCS still does not offer this as a built-in feature. There are a number of hosted open source tools or products that offer this sort of functionality, but it's not a built-in feature of GCS.