# Transfering File from FTP to Google Cloud Storage via a Static IP

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, ftp

I have created a [google cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip) to set up static IP as my customer required a specific IP address to access their FTP network. My goal now is to update this cloud function to connect to my customer and retrieve files to my own Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I've read various posts from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039500/auto-upload-remote-files-into-google-cloud-storage-via-ftp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage) and it seems that this is not very often done. Could I ask if this is possible? If so, could I ask for a pointer on which package to look into (I'm looking into `pysftp`  but no good documentations on using it via cloud function)? Lastly, am I correct that the [Secret Manager](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20secret%20manager&rlz=1C1RXQR_enCA999CA999&oq=google%20secret%20manager&aqs=chrome.0.0i512l5j69i60l3.2614j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is recommended for better privacy, especially since I will receive my customer's FTP password?

Thanks so much everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Per request, I am posting an answer here. Turns out I need to establish a SFTP connection. Both SFTP and FTP terms were floating around which makes it hard to get a better understanding, but I was able to use the paramiko package to connect to the desired server.